# printToPDF does not print all webContent view

Tags: javascript, electron

I am using the code below to save the webContents view into PDF file.

```
    saveReport() {
        const remote = require('electron').remote;
        const webContents = remote.getCurrentWebContents();

        webContents.printToPDF({
            pageSize: 'A3',
            landscape: false
        }, (err, data) => {
            remote.require('fs')
                .writeFile(TEMP_URL, data);
        });
    },
```

The view is a report and have a really long content inside it (see below).

[image]

Instead of showing a full view, I see a partial view inside a **single** page with a scrollbar. Below is the screenshot for the generated PDF,

[image]

**Expected behavior**

Just like a real browser, the generated PDF should contain all the view if a single page does not provide enough space, multiple pages should be generated.

I am thinking probably something wrong with my css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar requirement for my current project and i've noticed that when you use this api , you can customize how the pdf will be rendered by adding a css file to your main html with the media query set to print `media="print"`.

this css stylesheet will be applied only if you print something or export it to pdf via the api method `printToPdf()`.

if you are using some ui kit like photon or bootstrap , try to disable it and see if it helps.

last tip: try to use the css property `page-break-before: always;`

Hope this helps